# Populating an array and displaying its contents into a rich edit on a different form

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

This is the error I get when I click the `btnInfoClick`

> Debugger Exception Notification
>   Project_PAT_Phase_3.exe raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 004047E0 in module 'Project_PAT_Phase_3.exe' 'Read of address 00000022'.

The program runs smoothly without any errors until I click the button as shown in my code. Please I would appreciate your help.

```
unit Navigation;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls, InfoPopUp;

type
  Tvector = Array[1..14] of string;
  TFrmNavigation = class(TForm)
  btnVote: TButton;
  RdgInfo: TRadioGroup;
  Label2: TLabel;
  btnInfo: TButton;
 procedure btnInfoClick(Sender: TObject);
 private

public
 MyFile : TextFile;
 sLine : string;
 sArrayParty : Tvector;
end;

var
  FrmNavigation: TFrmNavigation;

implementation


procedure TFrmNavigation.btnInfoClick(Sender: TObject);
var
 K : integer;
 iCheck : integer;
begin
FrmInfo.Visible := true;
K := 1;
iCheck := 0;

if FileExists('PartyInfo.txt') <> True
then
  begin
    MessageDlg('File does not exist',mtError,[mbOK],0);
    Exit;
    end;// end of If statement

AssignFile(MyFile,'PartyInfo.txt');
Reset(MyFile);

while NOT eof(MyFile) do
 begin
  Inc(K);
  Readln(MyFile,sLine);
  sLine := sArrayParty[K];
end;//end of While
  closefile(MyFile);


 case RdgInfo.ItemIndex  of
 0 : begin
     FrmInfo.Caption := 'African Christian Democratic Party (ACDP)';
     FrmInfo.redOutput.Text := sArrayParty[1];
     end;
 1 : begin
     FrmInfo.Caption := 'African National Congress (ANC)';
     FrmInfo.redOutput.Text := sArrayParty[2];
     end;
 end;
```

the last `end.` below is where the error pops up in the code but its in the project unit which is weird cause when i had a breakpoint the exception would stop the program at the while loop.

```
program PAT_Phase_3;

uses
  Forms,
  WelcomePage in 'WelcomePage.pas' {frmWP},
  Navigation in 'Navigation.pas' {FrmNavigation},
  InfoPopUp in 'InfoPopUp.pas' {FrmInfo};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TfrmWP, frmWP);
  Application.CreateForm(TFrmNavigation, FrmNavigation);
  Application.CreateForm(TFrmInfo, FrmInfo);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: And **where exactly** (on which line of the code) does this error happen? I'm sure you've debugged it through, right?

Comment: So when you put a debugger breakpoint on the first line and run your app, and step through the code, which line causes the exception?

Comment: Kinda makes me sad when I see code like this.

Comment: yeah i get no errors on any specific line i get that pop up error and thats all, the program just stops running from there

Comment: @user What do you mean? Do you know about the debugger?

Comment: Where is FrmInfo Instantiated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message, with an address so close to zero, indicates that you are accessing a nil object reference. Most likely FrmInfo is nil. Or perhaps sArrayParty is nil. Use the debugger to confirm where the error is. Obviously it's an error to refer to a nil reference.

When you get an error like this, use the debugger, configured to break on exceptions, to point you at the line of code that faults. Then try to work out why that line of code fails.

If you are presented with hundreds of lines of code, it's hard to work out where a fault is. If you can concentrate on a single line of code, it's much easier. Time for you to learn to debug.

Comment: I believe hes actually accessing uninitialized array. `ReadLn(MyFile, sLine); sLine := sArrayParty[K]` makes no sense.

Comment: Read my answer again and heed the advice. Use the debugger. Which line throws the error.

Comment: Gee, I thought we weren't supposed to be answering "broken questions" - (at least that's what you just told me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530665/delphi-7-working-fast-string#comment28981222_19531423) - which is it?  :-)

Comment: how do i set it to exceptions?

Comment: @user in debugging options, the setting is named Break on exception or similar.

Comment: @KenWhite You think that it's not a nil pointer dereference? The fact that we don't know which pointer is not nil does not mean that we cannot explain **how** to solve the problem.

Comment: I did that. See my comment to the OP: "So when you put a debugger breakpoint on the first line and run your app, and step through the code, which line causes the exception?". My answer (that you objected to) directly addressed the code posted, but you took exception (pun intended) because the question wasn't clear enough. I'm asking you to explain the difference, since they both address a vaguely stated question that is lacking detail.

Comment: @KenWhite I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: I would bet sArrayParty is nil...How are you declaring it...
Where's the code to allocate for sArrayParty...and to actually give it a value...and then dispose of it...or if it's bounded...where's the bound checks...

Comment: please excuse my insolence, but when i set a breakpoint to handle exceptions the error pops up where i put the break point , at the last loop of the while. whats weird is that when i step it the Readln function is meant to fill sLine with the first line of my text file into sLine but instead its empty, i dont know why, and if sLine is empty each time it gets assigned to my array could it be filling the array with empty strings, the array was set from 1..14 so on the 15th loop the program gives me the exception at the line `while NOT eof(MyFile) do`

Comment: Don't set a break point. Go to the debuggon options and set break on exception, and then run until programme breaks on av.

Comment: @KenWhite I won't respond to ad hominem attacks

Comment: ive added the rest of the unit code including the declaration of the array

Comment: im trying to find out how to start the debugging process.. how do i , start it?

Comment: F9 just runs the program

Comment: No, F9 runs the program under the debugger.

Comment: ok i done it but it doesnt break anywhere when the exception pops up.

Comment: Then you need to enable the setting that I keep mentioning. Why have you not done that crucial step? Or perhaps you told Delphi to ignore EAccessViolation. Read this http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32015

Comment: i cant find any setting that resembles that step.

Comment: Keep looking. I'm not at a computer right now. Read the documentation for D7. Look for the sections on debugger options.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan check what ive added above thats where the program stops me at but its in the project unit, not exactly sure.

Comment: WHOA! `sLine := sArrayParty[K];` notice anything strange about this line?

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi you can set forms to AutoCreate or not via a project setting.  If your project is not auto creating all forms, then your FrmInfo is going to be nil. Add this code before your 
`FrmInfo.Visible := true;` line and see if it gets you further.

```
if FrmInfo = nil then
  FrmInfo := TFrmInfo.Create(nil);
```